# How do I get content from a QCombobox item by selecting an item?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I made this code, but it returns the previous value.

Code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import sys 
class LoginForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        layout = QGridLayout()
        choices = ['1', '2', '3']

        btHome = QPushButton('Button',self)
        btHome.clicked.connect(self.callback)

        self.CmbBx_Cod = QComboBox()
        self.CmbBx_Cod.addItem('Select a value')

        for choices in choices:
            self.CmbBx_Cod.addItem(choices)
        self.CmbBx_Cod.view().pressed.connect(self.callback)

        layout.addWidget(btHome, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.CmbBx_Cod, 0, 2)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
    
    def callback(self):
        code = self.CmbBx_Cod.currentText()
        print(f'code {code} selected!')

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    form = LoginForm() 
    form.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

When I click the button I have the value I want, but I wanted it when I selected a code. Is there any other method of doing this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using the `pressed` signal of the view, instead of [`currentIndexChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) or [`currentTextChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentTextChanged)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

In the first place, it should be understood that the pressed signal is emitted as soon as the mouse is placed with the button pressed on an item, but that is not used by the QComboBox to update the current text, but rather for stability the clicked signal that is emitted when the mouse is released, so in your logic you are trying to get the current text before it is updated so you get that unexpected behavior.

### Proper solution

If you want to get the item pressed then you should not use the QComboBox but directly the QModelIndex sent in the signal:

```py
def callback(self, index):
    code = index.data()
    print(f'code {code} selected!')
```

If instead you want to get the displayed text after releasing the mouse then you can use the clicked signal of the view, or better the currentTextChanged or currentIndexChanged signal.

```py
class LoginForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        layout = QGridLayout()
        choices = ["1", "2", "3"]

        btHome = QPushButton("Button", self)
        btHome.clicked.connect(self.callback)

        self.CmbBx_Cod = QComboBox()
        self.CmbBx_Cod.addItem("Select a value")

        for choices in choices:
            self.CmbBx_Cod.addItem(choices)
        self.CmbBx_Cod.currentTextChanged.connect(self.callback)

        layout.addWidget(btHome, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.CmbBx_Cod, 0, 2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def callback(self, code):
        print(f"code {code} selected!")
```

If you want to get the current text by pressing the button then you must create another slot:

```
class LoginForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        layout = QGridLayout()
        choices = ["1", "2", "3"]

        btHome = QPushButton("Button", self)
        btHome.clicked.connect(self.button_callback)

        self.CmbBx_Cod = QComboBox()
        self.CmbBx_Cod.addItem("Select a value")

        for choices in choices:
            self.CmbBx_Cod.addItem(choices)
        self.CmbBx_Cod.currentTextChanged.connect(self.combo_callback)

        layout.addWidget(btHome, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.CmbBx_Cod, 0, 2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def button_callback(self):
        self.printer(self.CmbBx_Cod.currentText())

    def combo_callback(self, code):
        self.printer(code)

    def printer(self, code):
        print(f"code {code} selected!")
```

Comment: The problem now is when you push the button, it prints a "False" code

Comment: @AlejandroCondori You have to implement another slot where you get the information. Remember: Each signal brings different information, do not think that by a divine miracle your code will work

Comment: @AlejandroCondori I have realized that you are another user so I should point out to you: The answers in SO do not aim to solve all the problems of the OP but the one that is expressly indicated, SO is not a tutorial service. Imagine if we wanted to correct each post then we would never finish.

Comment: @ eyllanesc I am new to this, but as you said, answers are only to solve the problem, but his button was working fine before the changes. Now,  you fixed the problem but generated another one. That is the reason I said that.

Comment: @AlejandroCondori I'm not looking at all the things so thanks for letting me know so I have already corrected it properly. Please if you are new then read [ask] and [answer]

Comment: I admit my answer was wrong, so I deleted it.